# Custom metabox translation

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox

I have created a custom post types and added some custom metaboxes and now I am wondering witch translation plugin I use for my site?

I don't have experience with none of them, so I don't know who will support my custom metaboxes and who will not.

Comment: The answers people have given so far have to do with internationalizing your content... that is, allowing the strings your code adds to the admin section and/or displays on the front end to be translated. I took your question to mean something different: you're adding custom content and want to be be able to display it in multiple languages within your theme. Can you clarify your question a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [Internationalizing Your Plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin#Internationalizing_Your_Plugin) codex entry to get a better understanding of WordPress Translations.

and read [I18n for WordPress Developers](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers) after that you will know that if you coded your custom post types and metaboxes the right way with Translatable strings , all plugins work in the same way of looking for these strings.

and i would suggest using [**Codestyling Localization**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/) plugin which create a UI for translating plugins and themes inside WordPress admin.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to translate your plugin yourself: http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress

Answer (score 0):

[WPML](http://wpml.org) fully supports custom post types, custom meta boxes, custom taxonomies and more.